# Be done with [gtd]

Tags: discussion, tag-cleanup-request

The [gtd tag](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/gtd) is about [getting things done](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Getting_Things_Done) which is a method or strategy for productivity.

All the questions could easily be retagged as [productivity](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/productivity) or even [time-management](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/time-management) or [time tracking](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/time-tracking) (why aren't those synonyms?) or most likely - *closed as off-topic*.

Comment: There were 23 questions with this tag.  The tag was completely irrelevant for a few and I just removed those.  Of the remainder, the majority are off-topic software requests.  I voted to close those that weren't already closed.  There are only six questions plus one that's closed as a duplicate that are on topic.  The tag is about a method, not a particular application, and not many people are familiar with it.  A more generic tag would probably be better at attracting answers.  Flip side: for a couple of questions, the only answers of interest to the OP are ones that reflect the GTD approach.